# Netbeans Remote Synchronize doesn't list files when a subdirectory is used as upload directory

Tags: netbeans, ftp, synchronization, hosting, cpanel

I've setup several sites previously to use Netbeans Remote Synchronization so I can edit files on the server from my machine and it has worked perfectly.

The problem I'm having right now is that when my FTP configuration in Netbeans uses the root folder it lists everything correctly but when I use a sub directory for example website.com/subdir as the upload directory or as the FTP initial directory the sync results come up blank - doesn't list anything at all on the remote side except directories in that sub directory.

My PC is a windows 7 64 bit machine, and the server is a standard shared hosting account running CPanel.

Also, I have been able to run the subdir synchronization on a different pc, could it be the firewall on this one? If so, why does it list the root folder properly?

Has anyone else had this issue? Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Strange... in most of my projects i always work in subfolders instead of the ftp root without any problem. You say that you don't see anything besides the subfolders in that directory. Does it mean that you can't see the files?

Comment: Hi, found the problem. The FTP path on this PC required the /public_html before the subfolder paths. i.e. essentially ftp://mydomain.com/public_html/path/to/subfolder

This wasn't the case on my laptop as I used the subfolder path right after the domain i.e. ftp://mydomain.com/path/to/subfolder and it worked fine, different versions of netbeans perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem. The FTP path on this PC required the /public_html before the subfolder paths. i.e. essentially ftp://mydomain.com/public_html/path/to/subfolder

This wasn't the case on my laptop as I used the subfolder path right after the domain i.e. ftp://mydomain.com/path/to/subfolder and it worked fine, different versions of netbeans perhaps.